# Fatal error: Class '..' not found

Tags: php, elasticsearch, symfony

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch via the PHP API in `symfony`.
I have installed `Elasticsearch` via `composer`.

This is my code that is being called:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\ElasticsearchQuery;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

class ElasticsearchQuery
{
private $Host = ['http://localhost:9200'];
private $client;
private $index = "homestead";

public function  __construct()
{
    $this->client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
        >setHosts($Host)->build();
}

public function execute($verb, $params)
{
    switch ($verb) {
    case "create":
        $response = $client->index($params);
        break;
    case "read":
        $response = $client->get($params);
        break;
    case "search":
        $response = $client->search($params);
        break;
    case "delete":
        $response = $client->delete($params);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

and the error I am getting:

> Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\ElasticsearchQuery\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder' not found

I don't want it to look for Elasticsearch in my AppBundle, I want it to look for it in the vendors.
How do I do that?

edit: using **use \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;** or **Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()** makes no difference

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got it _exactly_ wrong the first time ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
```

This should be either

```
$this->client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
```

or (since you've already imported that class into your namespace)

```
$this->client = ClientBuilder::create()
```

Comment: I edited my code to be
....
use \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
...
$this->client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($host)->build();

but I'm still getting an error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function AppBundle\ElasticsearchQuery\setHosts()

Comment: You're missing a `-`.  `->setHosts`, not `>setHosts`.

Comment: And please remove the leading \ in `use \...`, I was completely wrong about this. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php says: "the leading backslash is unnecessary and not recommended"